# Combing Columns after Transposing Columns Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

Suppose I have a set of data frames

df1 is

```
   ID       C1
0  0  0.000000
1  1  0.538516
2  2  0.509902
3  3  0.648074
4  4  0.141421
```

df2 is

```
  ID        C1
0  0  0.538516
1  1  0.000000
2  2  0.300000
3  3  0.331662
4  4  0.608276
```

and df3 is

```
  ID        C1
0  0  0.509902
1  1  0.300000
2  2  0.000000
3  3  0.244949
4  4  0.509902
```

I then go ahead and transpose these three data frames.

```
df1 = df1.T
df2 = df2.T
df3 = df3.T
```

Now the data frames are :

df1 is

```
          0         1         2         3         4
ID        0         1         2         3         4
C1        0  0.538516  0.509902  0.648074  0.141421
```

df2 is :

```
                 0         1    2         3         4
ID               0         1    2         3         4
C1               0.538516  0  0.3  0.331662  0.608276
```

and df3 is :

```
                 0    1    2         3         4
ID               0    1    2         3         4
C1          0.509902  0.3  0  0.244949  0.509902
```

Can I somehow combine all data frames to have

```
0            1         2         3         4
0          0.538516  0.509902  0.648074  0.141421
0.538516     0        0.3       0.331662  0.608276
0.509902     0.3      0         0.244949  0.509902
```

And then sort rows individually , so that each row in the resulting data frame is sorted ?

For instance the data frame with sorted rows would be

```
0  0.141421  0.509902  0.538516  0.648074
0  0.3       0.331662  0.538516  0.608276
0  0.244949  0.3       0.509902  0.509902
```

I'm having problems with concat since I've transposed the data frames.

All help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** sorted data set and without transposing:

```
In [64]: pd.DataFrame([np.sort(x['C1'].values) for x in dfs], columns=d1.index)
Out[64]:
     0         1         2         3         4
0  0.0  0.141421  0.509902  0.538516  0.648074
1  0.0  0.300000  0.331662  0.538516  0.608276
2  0.0  0.244949  0.300000  0.509902  0.509902
```

**Explanation:**

```
In [67]: d1
Out[67]:
   ID        C1
0   0  0.000000
1   1  0.538516
2   2  0.509902
3   3  0.648074
4   4  0.141421

In [68]: d1['C1'].values
Out[68]: array([ 0.      ,  0.538516,  0.509902,  0.648074,  0.141421])

In [69]: np.sort(d1['C1'].values)
Out[69]: array([ 0.      ,  0.141421,  0.509902,  0.538516,  0.648074])

In [70]: [np.sort(x['C1'].values) for x in dfs]
Out[70]:
[array([ 0.      ,  0.141421,  0.509902,  0.538516,  0.648074]),
 array([ 0.      ,  0.3     ,  0.331662,  0.538516,  0.608276]),
 array([ 0.      ,  0.244949,  0.3     ,  0.509902,  0.509902])]
```

now we can create a DataFrame from the list of sorted NumPy arrays, specifying `d1.index` as columns:

```
In [71]: pd.DataFrame([np.sort(x['C1'].values) for x in dfs], columns=d1.index)
Out[71]:
     0         1         2         3         4
0  0.0  0.141421  0.509902  0.538516  0.648074
1  0.0  0.300000  0.331662  0.538516  0.608276
2  0.0  0.244949  0.300000  0.509902  0.509902
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! how would I do about sorting each row ? I ask this since the C1 has been lost. I'm sorry if this is a trivial question , I'm extremely new to pandas.

Comment: @Anant, you will have the same order as in the `dfs` list

Comment: is sorting not possible ? I sorted my transposed data frame based on C1. The sorted order however was lost on using concat. I think its because indices are ordered together on concatenation. Any way to get around this ?

Comment: @Anant, i'm not quite sure i understand correctly... Could you post your desired DF (if it differs from the posted one)? PS why do you say `C1` is lost?

Comment: I've added some details to the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Anant, i've updated my answer - is that what you want?

Comment: Yes! Thanks a ton for this. I'll need to work on understanding how this works though. Many Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## Setup

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'C1': [0.0, 0.538516, 0.509902, 0.648074, 0.141421],
        'ID': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'C1': [0.538516, 0.0, 0.3, 0.331662, 0.608276],
        'ID': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
        'C1': [0.509902, 0.3, 0.0, 0.244949, 0.509902],
        'ID': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

## Solution(s)

### 1

It looks as though your `ID` column is important an maybe that's what you want to join on.  I'd set that as your index and then combine.

To sort each row, I'd leave as columns and apply a `sort_values`

```
df = pd.concat(
    [d.set_index('ID') for d in [df1, df2, df3]], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().values).T

ID    0         1         2         3         4
0   0.0  0.141421  0.509902  0.538516  0.648074
1   0.0  0.300000  0.331662  0.538516  0.608276
2   0.0  0.244949  0.300000  0.509902  0.509902
```

### 2

Get your dataframe and sort in `numpy`

```
df = pd.concat([d.set_index('ID').T for d in [df1, df2, df3]], ignore_index=True)

v = df.values
a = v.argsort(1)
i = np.arange(a.shape[0])[:, None]
df.loc[:] = v[i, a]

df

ID    0         1         2         3         4
0   0.0  0.141421  0.509902  0.538516  0.648074
1   0.0  0.300000  0.331662  0.538516  0.608276
2   0.0  0.244949  0.300000  0.509902  0.509902
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! how would I do about sorting each row ? I ask this since the C1 has been lost.  Also , If I sort each row on transposing , the sorted order is lost after I concatenate the dataframes

Comment: @Anant this was not specified in your question.  I do not understand exactly what you need from your comment alone.  It would be better to follow up with another posted question.  That way you can include more information in regards to specifically what you want to see.

Comment: I've added details to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the sorted version too! Really appreciate it